# Data in global Variable is not accessible on other page in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, global-variables

I want to access the user data as global in whole website. I make a global array `UserData`and push the user data at login time

```
        $.getJSON(targetUrl,data,function(response) {
             if(response.success){
             UserData.push(response.userData);//push the user data in global variable 

             } else{
                alert(response.error);
             }
         });//ajax request
```

It successfully pushes in array `UserData`. But when successful login redirects to welcome page. The data is not accessible on that page. It shows empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global variables are not stored site-wide, they are only available as long as you stay on the same page. If you need to store variables at the client that persists between page reloads, use a cookie or Local Storage.

There are many examples on how to set and get local storage variables using some simple methods (just use google), and there is some decent shims for legacy browsers available at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage

If you stick to cookies, there are some simple jQuery plugins that you can use, just google it.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to maintain variables between page loads unless you use something like a cookie to store your variables. Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for info on how to use cookies from javascript.